# The logic of “must_change_password=true” not implemented

Tags: cnosdb

The logic of “must_change_password=true” not implemented  \n
I follow the execution flow as follows.

```
# root
public ❯ create user user004 with password='user004', must_change_password=true;
Query took 0.508 seconds.
public ❯ create tenant tenant001;
Query took 0.274 seconds.
public ❯ alter tenant tenant001 add user user004 as member;
Query took 0.273 seconds.
# user004
cnosdb-cli -u user004 -p user004 -t tenant001
CnosDB CLI v2.4.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "user004", password: Some("user004"), private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "tenant001", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, receive_data_encoding: None, send_data_encoding: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false }
public ❯ show queries;
+----------------------+---------+---------------+------------+----------+
| query_id             | user    | query         | state      | duration |
+----------------------+---------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 11842856476853161823 | user004 | show queries; | SCHEDULING | 1        |
+----------------------+---------+---------------+------------+----------+
Query took 0.278 seconds.
public ❯ select * from information_schema.databases;
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| tenant_name | database_name | ttl | shard | vnode_duration | replica | precision |
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
Query took 0.287 seconds.
public ❯ \q
➜  ~ cnosdb-cli -u user004 -p user004 -t tenant001
CnosDB CLI v2.4.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "user004", password: Some("user004"), private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "tenant001", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, receive_data_encoding: None, send_data_encoding: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false }
public ❯ select * from information_schema.databases;
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| tenant_name | database_name | ttl | shard | vnode_duration | replica | precision |
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
+-------------+---------------+-----+-------+----------------+---------+-----------+
Query took 0.288 seconds.
public ❯
```

version: cnosdb 2.4.0, revision e7242a2f818e77878e20c19a9d52b1b04c27032f

Here's my take: When we receive a user request, and we're running a security check in CnosDB, we check if the user's password has been set. If it hasn't been set, we'll throw an error message saying 'Please set the user password.'